# Will my India based Visa debit card work in the USA or do I need a chip based EMV card?

Tags: united-states, debit-card, visa, atm

I have an international debit card by VISA issued in India. The card has magnetic stripe. Will the ATM card be valid in the USA or do i need a chip based EMV card?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the international debit cards issued in India are still valid in US and do not need to be converted into CHIP based card.

Comment: Do you have a citation to confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

The machine knows if the card has a chip, and will prompt you to place your card in the chip reader. If there is no chip, it's just like normal.

Although it may be in the news a lot, the chip based cards are rarely enforced from places of business that I've seen. It seems those companies who were affected by large hacks in the previous years (Target comes to mind) are the ones who've made the switch. Many places don't even have the ability to do chip based payment. Think of all the local business who use Square or any number of iPad POS systems. And I imagine retailers are reluctant to pay the cost associated with replacing their perfectly functioning technology.

Comment: CHIP based card system was implemented recently. In last 10 days they just have asked me once to do chip based payment. So I guess you should be fine if your debit card is international debit card